# Why is the rating selected in the form not inster to the database?

Tags: python, django

So this is my code:

**models.py:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Companies'

    COMPANY_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Dissolved', 'Dissolved'),
    )

    COMPANY_SIZE_CHOICES = (
        ('Small', 'Small'),
        ('Medium', 'Medium'),
        ('Large', 'Large'),
    )
    
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)
    company_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, null=True)    
    company_vat_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    company_status = models.CharField(choices=COMPANY_STATUS_CHOICES, max_length=20, default='Active', null=True)
    company_size = models.CharField(choices=COMPANY_SIZE_CHOICES, max_length=20, default='Small', null=True)
    company_rating = models.ForeignKey(Company_rating, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)      

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

**views.py:**

```
def suppliers_create(request):  
    form = SuppliersForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = SuppliersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            company_name = form.cleaned_data['company_name']
            company_number = form.cleaned_data['company_number']            
            company_vat_number = form.cleaned_data['company_vat_number']
            company_status = form.cleaned_data['company_status']
            company_size = form.cleaned_data['company_size']
            company_rating = form.cleaned_data['company_rating']                                      
            Company.objects.create(
                company_name=company_name,
                company_number=company_number,                
                company_vat_number=company_vat_number,
                company_status=company_status,
                company_size=company_size,
                company_rating=company_rating,                
            )            
            return redirect('/suppliers')
    context = {
        'form': SuppliersForm()
    }
    return render(request, 'suppliers/suppliers_create.html', context)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class SuppliersForm(forms.Form):
    COMPANY_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('Active', 'Active'),
        ('Dissolved', 'Dissolved'),
    )

    COMPANY_SIZE_CHOICES = (
         ('Small', 'Small'),
         ('Medium', 'Medium'),
         ('Large', 'Large'),
    )

    COMPANY_RATING_CHOICES = (
        ('Perfect', 'Perfect'),
        ('Average', 'Average'),
        ('Bad', 'Bad'),
    )

    company_name = forms.CharField()
    company_number = forms.CharField()    
    company_vat_number = forms.CharField()
    company_status = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMPANY_STATUS_CHOICES, label='Company Status')
    company_size = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMPANY_SIZE_CHOICES, label='Company Size')    
    company_rating = forms.ChoiceField(choices=COMPANY_RATING_CHOICES, label='Company Rating')
```

The **company_rating** field on the form is displayed, but unfortunately what I selected is not inserted into the database, I don't see what I chose on admin. I guess it has to do with it being a ForeignKey table, but what could be the solution? I tried **ModelChoiceField** but it didn't work. Could you help me, please?

Comment: Use a `ModelForm`? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: Also how would you save a foreign key with just a string (Perfect, Average, Bad)? get the model instance (or at least the primary key) for that value to save it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `SuppliersForm` is closely related to the `Company` Model, it'll be best to make use of a ModelForm. A ModelForm will reuse the field definitions in its associated Model and can handle the creation of the database object.

You should also make the `company_rating` field on the Company model a choice field, similar to the `company_status` and `company_size` fields.

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    ...

    COMPANY_RATING_CHOICES = (
        ('Perfect', 'Perfect'),
        ('Average', 'Average'),
        ('Bad', 'Bad'),
    )
    ...
    company_rating = models.CharField(choices=COMPANY_RATING_CHOICES, max_length=20, default='Perfect', null=True)
```

forms.py

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class SuppliersForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'company_name': _('Company Name'),
            'company_number': _('Company Number'),
            'company_vat_number': _('Company Vat Number'),
            'company_status': _('Company Status'),
            'company_size': _('Company Size'),
            'company_rating': _('Company Rating'),
        }
```

views.py

```
def suppliers_create(request):  
    
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form = SuppliersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():            
            form.save()       
            return redirect('/suppliers')
    else:
        form = SuppliersForm()
    return render(request, 'suppliers/suppliers_create.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thank you! :) You are great! :)